# Matrix multiplication dimensions confusing

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, torchtext

I am following this tutorial https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/nlp/deep_learning_tutorial.html#example-logistic-regression-bag-of-words-classifier

`nn.Linear(vocab_size, num_labels)`
means that the matrix shape is `num_labels x vocab_size`

bow_vector dimensions is `1 x vocab_size` and input expected for nn.linear is `batch_size x features`

Now, we are multiplying `num_labels x vocab_size` matrix by `1 x vocab_size`. Thus, the dimensions don't match for matrix multiplication. What am I missing here? :thinking:

https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/matrix-multiplication-dimentions-confusing/79376?u=abhigenie92

Answer (score 0):

You mis-understanding in `nn.Linear`. Let me point it out for you a bit.

`nn.Linear(vocab_size, num_labels)` doesn't mean that the matrix shape is `num_labels x vacab_size`.

The original is `nn.Linear(input_dim, output_dim, bias=True)`. Let say you have 3 points in 3D space and you want to projects those points to 2D space. So you just create a Linear layer that can helps you do that => `nn.Linear(3, 2, bias=True)`.

Examples:

```
linear_function = nn.Linear(3, 2, bias=True) # you have just created a function
a_3D_point = torch.Tensor([[1, 1, 1]])
a_2D_point = linear_function(a_3D_point)
```

Basically, `nn.Linear()` just help you created a function that can do the projection.

So you may wonder how `nn.Linear` can help you do the projection. Well, it pretty easy in math when the projection is just `y = Wx + b` or `y = Wx` (in case the bias=False) where `W` is weight and `b` is bias and both of them will be created randomly by `nn.Linear`. Check it out by:

```
print(list(linear_function.parameters()))  # Unchecked since I use my iPad to write this answer
```

================

Mapping to your case, the BowClassifier as my understanding it just try to classify the sentence into the finite classes. One of the easiest way to do is using one hot vector which has the shape of `n x vocab`.

`n` denotes that you have `n` sentence, but vocab in the second dimension now plays the role of features that represents each sentense.

You now you want to classify n sentences into `num_labels` class, just do the projection.

```
input = ...  # shape: [n x vocab]
classify_fn = nn.Linear(vocab, num_labels)
output = classify_fn(input)

# sigmoid or softmax to get the probability here
...
```